# how to get a column of a rhandsontable to round to and display only whole numbers?

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

So something like:

```
format="0,0.00"
```

will always round and display 2 decimal places.

What is the pattern that I need to assign to format in order to get it to display only whole numbers?

Comment: You should ask an example of the result you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Use `format = '0a'`, you can see the whole documentation [here](https://jrowen.github.io/rhandsontable/#formatting).

Comment: But I want all of the whole number digits to be displayed. I only want to truncate the decimals.

Comment: This format would set fx 173.56 = 173, if this is not what you want I am not sure I understand your definition of whole numbers? Could you provide an example?

Comment: That will round to 174. Furthermore, it will turn 2000 to 2k, 2000000 to 2m. I don't want that.

Comment: I would suggest to create a temporary df, update the format of the column and then use this dataframe to render the rhandsontable. Basic but will work.

Comment: ganidat may not want to modify the underlying data, it seems he/she just wants to display in a specific format. I have the same question too.