# How to hide digits from a rhandsontable element in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I understood that `rhandsontable` is based on the general `handsontable` JS libary itself using the `numebro` JS library.

However it seems that `numebro` does not allow to round the display in R of a figure in a hot table such as 13.4 to 13 and 13.6 to 14 (e.g. hidding digits, just in the display, not in the actual underlying data) which is a quite basic need and something DT can manage quite well. Is there a way to handle the hot **display** without modifying underlying data? I think this is the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57566553/how-to-get-a-column-of-a-rhandsontable-to-round-to-and-display-only-whole-number). Using the `'a'` format is not a solution since for instance 1,154,521.5 will apear as 1.1m.

Below an example from jrowen's github official page:

```
DF = data.frame(int = 1:10, float = rnorm(10), cur = rnorm(10) * 1E5,
                lrg = rnorm(10) * 1E8, pct = rnorm(10))

rhandsontable(DF, width = 550, height = 300) %>%
  hot_col("float", format = "0.0") %>%
  hot_col("cur", format = "$0,0.00") %>%
  hot_col("lrg", format = "0a") %>%
  hot_col("pct", format = "0%")
```

How to make the float 0.2 simply 0 until we edit the cell? Or the -13.18% simply -13%?